# Passing NULL to a function (NOT a pointer)

Tags: c, null

I want to know what would happen if I pass NULL to a function that is expecting a struct. The way I have things set up (which may be problematic), it is entirely possible for my "print a struct" function to be given NULL. If I left it alone, would it do anything? Do I need to check for it, and if so how? Or should I just safeguard against passing NULL to that function altogether?

I can't ask it to check if the struct variable it's given == NULL (struct can't be compared to void *). But I don't want the code to break if it does get sent NULL, I want to know that it was sent NULL. This is also all in debugging stages, the final product wouldn't send NULL to the print function.

Comment: Show code. Per the C standard, `NULL` is equivalent to either `0` or `(void *) 0`. If either of these is as an argument for a parameter declared as a structure type, the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic message, and compilers will typically reject such code. You can pass `NULL` for a parameter that is a pointer to a structure, but you say you are not doing that. Show actual code to clarify and explain.

Comment: You can't. If you pass struct by value, some chunk of memory has to be copied. You can have a special value in some field inducating other fields are initialized (or aren't).

Answer (score 1):

Passing `NULL` to a function that expects legitimate data can have deleterious effects, even resulting in a program crash.  Here is how you can check if `NULL` was sent to a function that expects a structure pointer.  Whenever there is a possibility of `NULL` being sent to any function, it's smart to check for `NULL` before using that function's parameter, else undefined behavior ensues.

Tested code. Runnable version is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Gss7hjx8M).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct TagCStruct {
    int num1,num2;
    char name[20];
} cStruct;

int print_a_struct(cStruct *cs) 
{
    printf("\nStructure details:\n");
    if(cs) /* if not NULL */
    {
        printf("Name: %s.   Year: %d%d\n",
            cs->name, cs->num1,cs->num2 );
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Cannot print. Param cs is NULL!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    cStruct cSt = {20,23,"Ctime Structure"};
   
    if(!print_a_struct(NULL))
        puts("There was a problem printing the structure.");

    if(!print_a_struct(&cSt))
        puts("There was a problem printing the structure.");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    Structure details:
    Cannot print. Param cs is NULL!
    There was a problem printing the structure.

    Structure details:
    Name: Ctime Structure.   Year: 2023
```